# Collapsible List Item in navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have read the documentation of android Navigation Drawer but there is nothing on how to create collapsible/expandable List item in navigation drawer. I know something about android `ExpandableListView` but I think it is not the way to create it. 
I want to create such nested item:

[image]

Comment: If its a real question, it will make sense. Don't need to apologize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start with [`ExpandableListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) and writing your own [`ExpandableListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) and use that as your drawer item.

Comment: So the Listview of navigation drawer is just like a typical listview we use?

Comment: You can make any view be the drawer view. ListView seems the most common.

Comment: @Karakuri (or OP) How to make the adapter know which items are droppable and which are simply selectable?