# Sub menu for sliding menu in android

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I have a sliding menu app like Facebook user interface. I want to create a submenu as shown in the picture below.

How can we create a submenu like this?

Please anyone help me for this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `NavigationDrawer` can present any `View` as its content, therefore you can use any technique you want to create a layout of interest.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621517/2463035) for one possible solution.