# What would be the best strategy to design the below Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Here is a roughly sketched image: [image]

The problem scenario:

The header of the list contains an Image and two text views which come from a tableA

The MyLibrary section is a static text without a data source.

The create Group is also a textview with static text - without a source such as a Table or DB.

My Groups section is populated from a Database Table say tableB

I want the whole section to scroll, on scroll and not individual parts. Properly like a list scrolls. I dont want to use two lists as that will break the guidelines.

So some parts of this list are from a Database and some are defined on the fly. I have come across expandable list views and have worked with custom list views as well. So complexity would not be a problem here. However I am confused What to use, what would be the best option to fit in this scenario. Fast efficient and hassle free?

Comment: .......Were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: Hi Devrath, I have not started yet I want to myself more time to think how I will fir in everything. As I specified I have some rows whose layout is entirely different from others.

Comment: @ Skynet ....... You can programaticlly set the no of elements, how it looks, it all depends on your requirements .... You r Skynet .... John cornor won't stop you :D :D !

Comment: Hahahaha Yes mate, to think of the model, that is why I am taking time. You see Skynet has evolved over the time and John Cornor stands no chance :D

Answer (score 1):

try to use expandable listview in drawer.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

### [Android Custom Navigation Drawer with Expandablelistview](http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-custom-navigation-drawer-with.html)

[image]

**[Download the sample Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtd51lxypodvojf/NavigationDrawer.zip)**

---

***Also check::***

1. [ExpandableListView / Drill-Down in Sliding Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916692/expandablelistview-drill-down-in-sliding-menu)
2. [Collapsible List Item in navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621469/collapsible-list-item-in-navigation-drawer)

Comment: Cool, let me take a look there :)